# libsqlite3.0.dylib not found when build in a iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I trie to put my application in a physic iPhone but xCode tell me that the library libsqlite3.0.dylib is not found.

Error code :

ld: library not found for -lsqlite3.0
clang : error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I can't use libsqlite3.dylib because I deleted it by misteak and I don't find a download link.

The application work perfectly on the IOS Simulator.

Thanks for your help !!

EDIT !

I reinstalled xCode and use the sqlite3.dylib framework and work perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled xCode and use the sqlite3.dylib framework and work perfectly !